# ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 FireBase Google

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Using cocoa pods , install firebase:

```
  target ‘Ejemplo’ do
pod 'MOCA'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

Intall cocoa pods
But when I try to compile

> > Ld /Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Ejemplo.app/Ejemplo
> >     normal armv7
> >         cd /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo
> >         export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
> >         export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
> >         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> >     -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk
> >     -L/Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
> >     -L/Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher
> >     -L/Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac
> >     -L/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/MOCA -F/Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
> >     -F/Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
> >     -filelist /Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Intermediates/Ejemplo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ejemplo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ejemplo.LinkFileList
> >     -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=10.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Intermediates/Ejemplo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ejemplo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ejemplo_lto.o
> >     -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -all_load -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lMOCALib -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony
> >     -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework
> >     GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework
> >     MapKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework PassKit -framework
> >     Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework
> >     UIKit -lsqlite3.0 -lPods-Ejemplo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
> >     /Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Intermediates/Ejemplo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ejemplo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ejemplo_dependency_info.dat
> >     -o /Users/dortiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ejemplo-hknorfqqubdrwxbrvosftrtmrnle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Ejemplo.app/Ejemplo
>
> duplicate symbol _GSDK_NSClassFromString in:
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_56070eb5aec147705560f2b7c064869c.o)
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
>   duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getClass in:
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_56070eb5aec147705560f2b7c064869c.o)
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
>   duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getProtocol in:
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_56070eb5aec147705560f2b7c064869c.o)
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
>   duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_lookUpClass in:
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_56070eb5aec147705560f2b7c064869c.o)
>       /Users/dortiz/Documents/BEACONS/Ejemplo/Ejemplo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
>   ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Al ready , I clean and reinstall de pods.
To import firebase only , use
@import Firebase;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Firebase 3.11.1 build.

Try backing up to Firebase 3.11.0 by adding the following to your podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '3.11.0'
```

Update: February 14, 2017: Firebase 3.13.0 released today should fix the duplicate symbol issue.

Comment: its true or import as framework firebase is another option

Answer (score 5):

What helped me was going to `Build Settings` for the Project file (blue) and in the `Other Linker Flags` make sure you do not have `-ObjC -all_load` manually set. Those are not required when using Objective-C modules and Cocoapods as Cocoapods will properly add the right flags to your target.

[image: Other Linker Flags Section]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the `-all-load` flag from "other linker flag" in both project settings and target settings